# Cross reference figure appears as "??"

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm using Texmaker for a report and am fairly new to latex.

My cross referenced equations seem to appear just fine, but not my figures. I've labelled them and referenced the label using ref. I ran PDFLatex, then BibTex, then PDFLatex again, then Quick Build, but I keep getting "??"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\citationmode{abbr}
\citationstyle{dcu}
\begin{document}


\section{Results\label{results}}{}
\subsection{Measuring Detection Rate\label{detection}}{}
\subsubsection{Cross-correlation\label{crosscorrdetect}}

{
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{centering}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{corrDetectTest.png}
        \caption{This is the $CrossCorrelation.h5$. $2$ is the value}
    \end{centering}
    \label{corrdetectdiag}
\end{figure}
}

{\ref{corrdetectdiag} shows the resulting...} 

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{BIB_FILE}
\end{document}
```

I liked how math mode formats the text, so I used it every time I mention a file name, value, or equation.

Comment: Remove the `center` environment and place a `\centering` instead. Why is all your stuff in groups (between curlyy braces)?

Comment: "I liked how math mode formats the text, so I used it every time I mention a file name, value" *For the love of God and all things you hold holy, **do not do this!***. That said, cross-references require you compile twice. You'll note in the terminal LaTeX saying something like 'some references undefined'. Just run LaTeX again. If that doesn't work, let us know.

Comment: Can you post us a **complete-but-minimal** compilable example that shows the problem please?  Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: I've replaced center with \centering  but I get an error:
"! Missing \endcsname inserted."

I've tried compiling multiple times but it has not worked. That said, I'll keep trying, hoping for the best.

What is wrong with using math mode? I thought it emphasised the text a lot better than using italics did (as long as you're using single words)

Comment: @Thruston, I have added the complete example as an edit above.

Comment: `centering` is not an environment that you should `\begin{}` and `\end{}`. remove these and replace them with a single `\centering` after your `\begin{figure}`

Comment: @SeanAllred Is there anything wrong with the math mode preference mentioned before? You make it sound like it is a huge mistake.

Comment: @CaptainObv the biggest reason is that what you're typesetting *is not math*. If you want to use a special font for filenames and other identifiers, there are other ways to specify that font than abusing math mode. But, anyway, other things that will go wrong: hyphenation, underscores in filenames, loss of kerning, spacing if the identifiers contain characters TeX expects to be math operators, etc.

Comment: @CaptainObv Math mode for text is punished with ugly kernings between letters. Compare `\textit{abcffjj}` with `$abcffjj$`.

Comment: @CaptainObv Paul wrapped it up quite nicely -- what you're setting *isn't math* so it shouldn't be treated like that. It's best to define a new command (or use one from a package like `menukeys`) that will give it the proper treatment -- whatever you decide that to be -- consistently throughout.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest loading the `cleveref` package, then using the command `\cref{}` which automatically adds `fig.` to the referred image number. You can also choose between these options:

- `noabbrev`, it will change `fig.` to `figure`. It must be added as an option to the package. I would advise in favour of this option in case you plan to start a sentence with Figure and not Fig.
- `capitalise` (or `capitalize`) will set all references with a capital letter (so `Figure`), used the same way as above.
- Alternatively, you can select which is capitalised and which is not, by using `\cref` for lowercase, and `\Cref` for uppercase. See example:

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\citationmode{abbr}
\citationstyle{dcu}
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Results\label{results}}{}
\subsection{Measuring Detection Rate\label{detection}}{}
\subsubsection{Cross-correlation\label{crosscorrdetect}}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is the $CrossCorrelation.h5$. $2$ is the value}
    \label{corrdetectdiag}
\end{figure}

\Cref{corrdetectdiag} shows the resulting...\\

\cref{corrdetectdiag} shows the resulting...

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{BIB_FILE}
\end{document}
```